# Bloc does not send status after removing an item from the list

Tags: android, flutter, bloc

I'm new to flutter development and the bloc pattern and I'm trying to program a simple notes app. i have a home screen managed by a homebloc

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

   final homeBloc = HomeScreenBloc();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("CALL init state");
    homeBloc.add(LoadUserNoteEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeData = Theme.of(context);

    

    return BlocConsumer<HomeScreenBloc, HomeState>(
        bloc: homeBloc,
        
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! HomeScreenAction,
        listener: (context, state) {
          print("Listen for a state :  ${state.runtimeType}");
          if(state is AddNoteButtonPressed){
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddNotePage()));
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          print("Get a state :  ${state.runtimeType}");
          if(state is UserNoteListState){
            return  Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("Flutter Notes"),
              centerTitle: Platform.isAndroid ? false : true,
              actions: [
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.menu)),
              ],
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                onFabButtonPressed();
              },
              backgroundColor: themeData.colorScheme.primary,
              foregroundColor: themeData.colorScheme.onPrimary,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                const TopSection(),
                Flexible(
                  child: NoteListWidget(userNoteList: state.userNoteList)
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
          }else{
            return Text("Error");
          }
        },
      );
    
  }

  void onFabButtonPressed () {
     homeBloc.add(OnFloatingActionButtonPressed());
  }
}
```

When I start the application the status loads successfully and shows list of notes list. the navigation button successfully sends the event and receives the response to navigate to another screen. When I click on the button to remove the note the logic works fine. send the event the note is removed from the list and the various print confirm however flutter does not reissue the state to the ui to redraw the list without the elements. I know it probably depends on the fact that if bloc considers the state to be the same as the previous one, it doesn't trigger it. I've tried various fixes.. but I don't understand how to make the state differ in these cases.

Here my homeBloc code:

```
class HomeScreenBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {

  final getNoteUseCase = GetNoteUsesCase();
  final removeNoteUseCase = RemoveNoteUseCase(); 

  HomeScreenBloc() : super(UserNoteListState(userNoteList: [])) {

    

     on<OnFloatingActionButtonPressed>(navigateToAddnoteEvent); 
     on<LoadUserNoteEvent>(loadUserNoteData);
     on<RemoveNoteEvent>(removeNote);

     
  }

  FutureOr<void> navigateToAddnoteEvent(OnFloatingActionButtonPressed event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
      emit(AddNoteButtonPressed());
  }

  FutureOr<void> loadUserNoteData(LoadUserNoteEvent event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
     final data = List<NoteEntity>.from(getNoteUseCase.getNotelist()); 
     emit(UserNoteListState(userNoteList: data));
  }

  

  FutureOr<void> removeNote(RemoveNoteEvent event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
       removeNoteUseCase.removeNote(event.removeNote);
       emit(UserNoteListState(userNoteList: getNoteUseCase.getNotelist()).copyWith(getNoteUseCase.getNotelist()));
       
    }
}
```

here the state class

```
abstract class HomeState {
  const HomeState();
}

abstract class HomeScreenAction extends HomeState {}


class UserNoteListState extends HomeState with EquatableMixin {
  final List<NoteEntity> userNoteList;

  
  UserNoteListState({required this.userNoteList});
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];

  UserNoteListState copyWith (List<NoteEntity> userNoteList){
    return UserNoteListState(
      userNoteList: userNoteList
    );
  }
  
  
  
}

class AddNoteButtonPressed extends HomeScreenAction {
  AddNoteButtonPressed();
  
}
```

I expect that when I fire the RemoveNote event after removing the note from the list the event will be fired again to refresh the list.

Comment: Can you add the GetNoteUsesCase and RemoveNoteUseCase class just want to know what you are doing inside the classes, so that based on that i can propose a solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer I fixed it, as an absolute beginner I overlooked the fact that the state is not triggered if it is equal. I forced the execution by putting a clickAtTime parameter with the time in milliseconds and passed it to the equatable so that it doesn't consider them equal. I don't think it's a very suitable solution, if you have any other tips to avoid making the mistake again, I'm all ears.

Comment: So the changes that  you did are they mentioned above if not your can add them based on that i can give you the prefered solution. I don't  think this should be the proper solution an unnecessary use of the parameter just to let the equatable object to differentiate seems wrong.